# Javascript error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function OnSuccessPM(results) {
            $("#ChatBox").html("");
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $("#ChatBox").append(results[i].username + " : " + results[i].message + ". <br />");
            }
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("ChatBox");
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
            return false;
    }

MetamorphismApp.ChatService.GetPublicMessages(OnSuccessPM, OnFailurePM);   

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public List<Message> GetPublicMessages()
        {
            List<Message> getMsgsList = (List<Message>)HttpContext.Current.Application["Messages"];
            return getMsgsList;
        }
```

I get the following error in IE:

> length is null or not an object.

What is the solution?

Comment: How is this function invoked? What is passed as argument? `results` must pass a javascript array for this to work. Is it in your case? What is the `GetPublicMessages` function? How is it implemented? We can't help you if you don't provide more details.

Comment: What is `MetamorphismApp`? There is a problem in the way you consume the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest (but not the best, the best would be to fix what is being passed to your `OnSuccessPM` function) way would be to check the `typeOf` the `results` variable to make sure it is an Array and only proceed to the `results.length` line if it is.